# Oracle JDBC select with WHERE return 0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle10g

Similar question to:
[Strange problem with JDBC, select returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903488/strange-problem-with-jdbc-select-returns-null)
but people didn't ask for this.

My code:

```
public int myMethod(String day) throws SQLException{
  String sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = " + day;
  Connection connection = ConnFactory.get();
  PreparedStatement prepareStatement = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;
  int ret = -1;
  try{
      prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sql);
      if(resultSet.next()){
          ret = resultSet.getInt(1);
      }
  }
  catch(SQLException sqle){
      // closing statement & ResultSet, log and throw exception
  }
  finally{
     // closing statement & ResultSet
  }
  ConnFactory.kill(connection);

  return ret;
}
```

This code always return 0. I try to log sql before execution and try to run it in SQLdeveloper and get correct value (over 100).
When I remove WHERE, `sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable` query return number of all rows in table.
I use Oracle 10g with ojdbc-14.jar (last version from maven repo) and Java 6.

Comment: If it returns 0, there are no rows matching your WHERE. Plain and simple. Run the same query in a client (e.g. SQLDeveloper) and see what the result is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`day` has not been quoted correctly, I would suggest using a prepared statement *like* a prepared statement as follows:

```
...
try {
    prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = ?");
    prepareStatement.setString(1,day);
...
```

is the same as:

```
sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = '" + day + "'";
```

with several advantages over the latter (mainly security and performance). See:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 4):

First of all using sql like this is not advisable. Because it leads to SQL injection.

In the future try using like below and use PreparedStatement to execute

```
String sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = ? "
```

For your solution did you try

```
String sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = '" + day + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

karim79 is good answer, you forgot add apostrophe signs in your "day" value

```
String sql = "Select count(*) from MyTable WHERE someColumn = '" + day + "'";
```