# Oracle JDBC select count return 0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am having trouble when selecting a total number of registers in a table. This should return the number of columns to set up a dataModel, but it always returns 0.

I did use the `"'"` in my statement, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503133/oracle-jdbc-select-with-where-return-0?rq=1), but it didn't work.

I can't figure out why it's returning 0.

My code:

```
sql.append(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS QTT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1 = 1 ");

if (condition != null)
{
    sql.append(" AND SOME_COLUM_CHAR = '").append(ID).append("' ");
}
```

Comment: It is returning `0` because the `where` conditions are filtering out all the rows.  This would always occur if the table were empty.

Comment: Have you tried querying the table to make sure which data is there?

Comment: Also, show us the complete code, where you get the result from the ResultSet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle JDBC select with WHERE return 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503133/oracle-jdbc-select-with-where-return-0)

Comment: Also. That's an unsafe way of passing parameters to a query. Learn to use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: "This should return the number of columns" ... sounds like you want metadata.

Comment: @ericbn I queried the table in Oracle SQL Developer and there is data in my table.